# How to use Except inside Where Exists in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following SQL Server query I am trying to rewrite as LINQ:

```sql
-- find people not already in People table based on name match but 
-- other non-id elements not matching. Person_id will not match 
-- between tables. Need person_id at the end of it all.
select p1.person_id, p1.name, p1.birthdate, p1.address
from Persons1 p1
join Persons2 p2
  on p1.name = p2.name
where exists
(
  select p1.name, p1.birthdate, p1.address
  except
  select p2.name, p2.birthdate, p2.address
);
```

I want to use the `Except` set operator because it easily helps me identify unmatched data. However, I am falling a little short on how to convert this to a C# LINQ method syntax.

Here's an example:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
}

var sourcePeople = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { Id = 1, Name = "John Doe", Address = "Test Address1", Birthdate = DateTime.Today },
    new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Jane Doe", Address = "Test Address2", Birthdate = DateTime.Today },
    new Person { Id = 3, Name = "Doug Fir", Address = "Test Address3", Birthdate = DateTime.Today }
};

var destinationPeople = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { Id = 4, Name = "John Doe", Address = "Test Address1", Birthdate = DateTime.Today },
    new Person { Id = 5, Name = "Jane Doe", Address = "Test Address5", Birthdate = DateTime.Today },
    new Person { Id = 6, Name = "Doug Fir", Address = "Test Address3", Birthdate = DateTime.Today }
};
```

This gives me differences but without their ids. I can't include id  because then it would return every row since ids don't match

```cs
var result = sourcePeople
    .Select(i => new
    {
        i.Name,
        i.Birthdate,
        i.Address
    })
    .Except(destinationPeople
        .Select(p => new
        {
            p.Name,
            p.Birthdate,
            p.Address
        }))
    .ToList();
```

How can I return all `sourcePeople` that aren't in destination people? But only for the difference in the subset of properties like I used above. For this I would expect to see only Id 3.

```
var result2 = sourcePeople
    .Where(s => destinationPeople.???)
    .Select(s => s.Id);
```

And yes I know about `Any()` but I haven't a clue of how it would write up in this case.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @GuruStron It's SQL Server, but the SQL posted it just to show you what I'm trying to accomplish in C# LINQ

Comment: TBH EF Core is not an ideal tool for such manipulations. Have you considered using the [`MERGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), possibly wrapping it into stored procedure with [table valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters)?

Comment: @GuruStron `MERGE`... for a `SELECT`? Even when `MERGE` is a useful suggestion, [it should always come with caveats](https://sqlblog.org/merge).

Comment: @GuruStron Not looking for SQL Server solutions. Perhaps I should clarify, I am not trying to generate LINQ to SQL exact equivalent, the query is just to give you an idea of the data I am looking for. I just want to know how to write LINQ that would accomplish what they query is doing.

Comment: @AaronBertrand based on the naming of `PeopleToImport` I have assumed that final goal was not select. Maybe my assumption was wrong.

Comment: Have you tried using [Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN)?

Comment: @Trisped yes, but I can't even work out how the code would write up...

Comment: @ShandySawyer I have added an answer.  Please accept and up vote, or add a comment if it needs more refinement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except does not work with your example because you are only comparing objects, not collections.

Below is an example which implements your SQL statement:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
}

private static List<Person> TestLinq()
{
    var sourcePeople = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person { Id = 1, Name = "John Doe", Address = "Test Address1", Birthdate = DateTime.Today },
        new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Jane Doe", Address = "Test Address2", Birthdate = DateTime.Today },
        new Person { Id = 3, Name = "Doug Fir", Address = "Test Address3", Birthdate = DateTime.Today }
    };

    var destinationPeople = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person { Id = 4, Name = "John Doe", Address = "Test Address1", Birthdate = DateTime.Today },
        new Person { Id = 5, Name = "Jane Doe", Address = "Test Address5", Birthdate = DateTime.Today },
        new Person { Id = 6, Name = "Doug Fir", Address = "Test Address3", Birthdate = DateTime.Today }
    };

    var desiredSourcePeople = sourcePeople
        .Join(destinationPeople,
            sourcePerson => sourcePerson.Name,
            destinationPerson => destinationPerson.Name,
            (sourcePerson, destinationPerson) => new
            {
                SpId = sourcePerson.Id,
                SpName = sourcePerson.Name,
                SpBirthdate = sourcePerson.Birthdate,
                SpAddress = sourcePerson.Address,
                DpName = destinationPerson.Name,
                DpBirthdate = destinationPerson.Birthdate,
                DpAddress = destinationPerson.Address
            }
        )
        .Where(joinedPerson =>
            joinedPerson.SpBirthdate != joinedPerson.DpBirthdate
            || joinedPerson.SpAddress != joinedPerson.DpAddress)
        .Select(joinedPerson => new Person
        {
            Id = joinedPerson.SpId,
            Name = joinedPerson.SpName,
            Birthdate = joinedPerson.SpBirthdate,
            Address = joinedPerson.SpAddress
        })
        .ToList();

    return desiredSourcePeople;
}
```

If you are trying to avoid the complicated Where clause, you could write a method to do the comparison:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }

    public bool IsSameExceptId(Person person)
    {
        return Name == person.Name && Address == person.Address && Birthdate == person.Birthdate;
    }
}

private static List<Person> TestLinq()
{
    var sourcePeople = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person { Id = 1, Name = "John Doe", Address = "Test Address1", Birthdate = DateTime.Today },
        new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Jane Doe", Address = "Test Address2", Birthdate = DateTime.Today },
        new Person { Id = 3, Name = "Doug Fir", Address = "Test Address3", Birthdate = DateTime.Today }
    };

    var destinationPeople = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person { Id = 4, Name = "John Doe", Address = "Test Address1", Birthdate = DateTime.Today },
        new Person { Id = 5, Name = "Jane Doe", Address = "Test Address5", Birthdate = DateTime.Today },
        new Person { Id = 6, Name = "Doug Fir", Address = "Test Address3", Birthdate = DateTime.Today }
    };

    var desiredSourcePeople = sourcePeople
        .Join(destinationPeople,
            sourcePerson => sourcePerson.Name,
            destinationPerson => destinationPerson.Name,
            (sourcePerson, destinationPerson) => new
            {
                SourcePerson = sourcePerson,
                DestinationPerson = destinationPerson
            }
        )
        .Where(joinedPerson => !joinedPerson.SourcePerson.IsSameExceptId(joinedPerson.DestinationPerson))
        .Select(joinedPerson => joinedPerson.SourcePerson)
        .ToList();

    return desiredSourcePeople;
}
```

Also note that this second example stores the objects in joinedPerson rather than splitting out to just the desired values.

Comment: Because your `IsSameExceptId` method doesn't use `Expression<T>` this won't work to produce efficient SQL, instead it will have to load everything into memory first, which is usually undesirable.

Comment: @Dai The poster indicated "It's SQL Server, but the SQL posted it just to show you what I'm trying to accomplish in C# LINQ" in the comments, which (with the lack of a SQL tag) lead me to believe that they were not querying a database.

Comment: @Dai The poster also indicated "Not looking for SQL Server solutions. Perhaps I should clarify, I am not trying to generate LINQ to SQL exact equivalent, the query is just to give you an idea of the data I am looking for. I just want to know how to write LINQ that would accomplish what they query is doing".